# Java Mult Array From File

Tags: java, arrays

I have been having problem trying to get the program to work.  The first row in the array is set blank and it keep pushing out the last row in the array.

```
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("please enter the file name");
String name = console.next();
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(name));        

int length = input.nextInt();
int lengt = input.nextInt();

char[][] array = new char[length][lengt];

for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
   array[i] = input.nextLine().toCharArray();
}

for(int k = 0; k < array.length; k++){
    for(int s = 0; s < array[k].length; s++) {
        System.out.print(array[k][s]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}

input.close();
System.out.println();
```

Comment: Can you include the first few lines of your file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the adding the line `input.nextLine();` to your code like so:

```
int length = input.nextInt();
int lengt = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine();
char[][] array = new char[length][lengt];
```

I believe what is happening is you are reading the `int`'s to get `length` and `lengt`, but you are leaving the rest of that line. When you call `array[i] = input.nextLine().toCharArray();` the first time you are pushing the rest or the line with the `length` and `lengt` `int`'s. Since that is counted as the first line in your `for` loop you are not iterating over the last line.

Comment: great, here is how you can mark this as the accepted answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work